# Giving a default value to PaddingProperty changes nothing

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, default, dependency-properties

I have an ExtendedLabel which derives from System.Windows.Controls.Label.
I want to give default value for PaddingProperty.
I know that I can use OverrideMetadata method for this purpose.
But some how it doesn't work, *Padding* vallue still appears as **5,5,5,5** (which is default value for Label).

However everything works as expected for other properties like *Margin*.

```
    class ExtendedLabel : Label
{
    static ExtendedLabel()
    {

        PaddingProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ExtendedLabel), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new Thickness(0)));
        MarginProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ExtendedLabel), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new Thickness(0, 10, 0, 20)));
    }

    public ExtendedLabel()
    {
     //    this.Padding = new Thickness(0);
    }
}
```

[image: Property Values on runtime (using snoop tool)]

**PS:**
I don't want to set *Padding* at my constructor.
Because this avoids other developers from changing *Padding* value from their styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Padding` value is certainly set by the Label's default Style.

You may overwrite that value by a default Style for your ExtendedLabel class, by creating a ResourceDictionary called `Generic.xaml` in a `Themes` folder in the Visual Studio project that hosts the control.

`Generic.xaml` would contain a Style like this:

```
<Style TargetType="local:ExtendedLabel" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Label}}">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
</Style>
```

and it would be registered as default Style like this:

```
static ExtendedLabel()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
        typeof(ExtendedLabel),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ExtendedLabel)));
}
```